# Can not import log4j from CLASSPATH

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using linux and I have the following files in a directory:

1. logtest.java
2. log4j2.xml
3. log4j-api-2.13.1.jar
4. log4j-core-2.13.1.jar

In the logtest.java file, I am importing the log4j library with this line:

`import org.apache.logging.log4j.*;`

My CLASSPATH is `/path/to/directory:/path/to/directory/log4j-api-2.13.1.jar:/path/to/directory/log4j-core-2.13.1.jar` .

When I execute `javac logtest.java`, I get the following error:
`error: package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist`.

But when I execute `javac -cp /path/to/directory:/path/to/directory/log4j-api-2.13.1.jar:/path/to/directory/log4j-core-2.13.1.jar logtest.java`, it works.

Why is it unable to find the package without the -cp argument and from the CLASSPATH?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Windows: try `echo %CLASSPATH%` in a command prompt window / Linux or macOS: try `echo $CLASSPATH` in a terminal window to check what your `CLASSPATH` environment variable is really set to.

Comment: @Jesper I am using Linux Mint. I checked and the classpath is set to the correct place and in fact, the same classpath works when I use javac with -cp argument.